# PowerBI Troubleshooting Measure Error 'Column doesn't exist or doesn't have a relationship...'

Tags: powerbi, measure

I've been working in a practice PowerBI document and was able to get a measure to work, but now when I try to re-create the measure in the non-practice document, I get this error:

'The column 'Department Names[DESL]' either doesn't exist or doesn't have a relationship to any table available in the current context.'

[image: Error message 'The column 'Department Names[DESL]' either doesn't exist or doesn't have a relationship to any table available in the current context.']

The data and tables are exactly the same for both files.
I've compared the relationship in the model view and the relationship is the same.

[image]

Where else can I troubleshoot to figure out why the measure doesn't work? I feel like PowerBI did something automatically in my practice document that I need to implement.

Also, any great training suggestions would be swell.

Comment: Are you creating it as a measure or a column..I guess you have to do it as column

Comment: @balaji - Thanks for suggesting that. I realized when trying to add a calculated column, that there was a problem with the link to my data source. I fixed that link, and it's working now.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem with my database connection, which would have been nice if PowerBI had told me directly, instead of only throwing an error when I tried to connect the 2 sources.

I'm not done fixing the problem yet, but suspect that once that connection is good, I'll be able to relate the 2 columns in the 2 tables.

Comment: Also found that RELATED works like VLOOKUP and can only be used in a calculated column or part of an iterator function - not as a measure, I guess?
I'm really hating PowerBI. If I could only do this in SQL.